# Python - Sockets behaving oddly?

Tags: python, sockets

I have a client / server application, and it is very basic. The client sends the server a message with information containing a file name, the server then creates this file in the server directory, the client will then proceed to send all the binary data from the file that the client chose to the server (and the server writes it into the newly formed file). The server then needs to run this file and send all output back to client. It was working fine, until I hit this dead end and it keeps looping. Here's a simplified version of the code on the server:

```
if data_received.startswith("COMMAND:run_file"): #client tells server to create new file
    #create file
    while True:
        #Get binary data from client
        #If data is blank break
        #Write data to new file
    #Close file
    #Open up new file using subprocess
    p = Popen("python " + data[17:], shell=True,stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=STDOUT)
    print p.stdout.read() #Print output
```

Now whenever this code is run, the server will receive the binary data of the client's file fine, but then it will just sit there... waiting for something, and it is not waiting for a new command from the client (I know this much). I am confused, so could someone spot the (possibly) very obvious mistake I've made somewhere?

**Edit:**
I have found where it is getting stuck, and it is after

```
print p.stdout.read()
```

Now I have no clue why this is getting stuck.

Comment: what command do you use for getting binary data from the client?

Comment: The client sends data `s.sendall(data)` and the server receives data using `conn.recv(1024)`

Comment: I suggest that you trace `data_recieved`.  It is possible that the binary data is not the length you think it is.  Are you python 2 or python 3?  It might matter because of the difference between byte and string objects.  (Also, but probably unrelated, why are you using a shell?)

Comment: The binary data is what I expect, I can manually check the differences between the 2 files. I am using Python 2. And I dont know why I am using a shell, I am new to subprocess. lol

Comment: Since the subprocess you start is actually Python, you would better go with `multiprocessing` module instead of your own similar thing built with `subprocess`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use conn.recv(1024) it will wait until it receives data. And since you are in a while true loop, it will continuously try to receive data, if all the data is sent it doesn't receive anything (instead of 'blank data'). Therefore, your 'if data is blank' is never true.

Comment: Ok thank you. So how come the client `s.recv(1024)` doesn't do the same thing?

Comment: It does wait for the data as well, what do you think it does differently

Comment: confused with this answer: where does `conn.recv(1024)` come in the code snippet from the question? or `s.recv(1024)` ?

Comment: in the comments of the question

Comment: @Maaaaa I think I was just confused about how recv() works. Because I have previously done tests similar to this and the while loop worked. Obviously not in every circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

As said in my comment if the subprocess you start is Python, I would recommend to use the `multiprocessing` module.

However, to answer your question I think `stdout` is buffered, and `stdout.read()` will only return when the sub-process ends.

The solution would be to use `stdout.readline()` instead of `stdout.read()`.
Also, do not redirect `stderr` to `PIPE` if you are not reading `stderr`.